# JQuery change event not firing when input value changed from VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a large project which has been initially written in Jquery, and currently we are in the process of refactoring using VueJS. So basically, the case looks like this:

html

```
<div id="app">
     <input :value='myVal'/>
     <button type="button" @click="onClick">
        Press me
     </button>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myVal: 'a'
  },
  methods: {
   onClick() {
    this.myVal = 'b'
  }
}
})


$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
        alert('Value changed')
    })
})
```

My goal is to control the value from VueJS, but to be able to listen from JQuery to the changes of the input. The problem is that when the value of the input is changed from VueJS, I cannot see the alert "Hello" pop up. However, when I edit the input manually by typing something inside it, the alert pops up as expected. Any ideas who such a pattern can be made work ?

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4cy6szv/)

Comment: This cannot be done "automatically". The best thing is to migrate all the JQuery stuff to Vuejs, but until then, you can configure a Vuejs watch on the value and trigger a JQuery event (e.g. `$el.trigger("change")`, if I remember correctly)

Comment: I agree with phasing out jQuery, which I think is your goal.  One problem with your Vue code is the input should bind to v-model instead of value: ```<input v-model='myVal'/>```. You could also add a change handler to the input directly: ```<input v-model='myVal' @change="changeHandler"/>```

Answer (score 0):

use the `input` event. This will trigger immediately if you change the text of input field. change the code to

```
$(document).on('input', 'input', function() {
 alert('Value changed')
})
```

**NB: Better try to handle the change event in vue js. It is not good a practice for mix jquery and vue js**